# Float Stacked divs side by side without a column wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make stacked divs appear as though they are in a column. I am unable to directly edit the html due to the application being used. The problem is the right column is pushed farther down the document. I would like them to align at the top. Usually I would wrap each side in a div and float or inline-block them. I also am unable to use jQuery like .wrapAll() to inject the needed html into the document. Any help or reading would be appreciated. Thanks.

An example of the code is at this jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/itivae/30xhjwcz/5/

```
    <style>
        .content-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .div-1, .div-2, .div-3, .div-4, .div-5 {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 48%;
            clear: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        .div-6, .div-7, .div-8, .div-9, .div-10, .div-11, .div-12 {
            float: right;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 48%;
            clear: right;
            position: relative;
        }
   </style>
   <div class="content-wrapper">
       <!--This is the left column-->
       <div class="div-1">Content</div>
       <div class="div-2">Content</div>
       <div class="div-3">Content</div>
       <div class="div-4">Content</div>
       <div class="div-5">Content</div>
       <!--End left "column"-->
       <!--Start right column-->
       <div class="div-6">Content</div>
       <div class="div-7">Content</div>
       <div class="div-8">Content</div>
       <div class="div-9">Content</div>
       <div class="div-10">Content</div>
       <div class="div-11">Content</div>
        <div class="div-12">Content</div>
        <!--End right Column-->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is the relative position of the wrapper class and your width needs to be less than 100% for each side. Sometimes it's best to work back and think simple.

```
.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div-1, .div-2, .div-3, .div-4, .div-5 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.div-6, .div-7, .div-8, .div-9, .div-10, .div-11, .div-12 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ezcbkmo/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does fix the fiddle. Unfortunately it doesn't work in said application. There must be something else I've missed there.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the widths? You may want to do fixed pixel widths.

Comment: I've also edited my answer to include a width to the wrapper

Comment: I tried that it didn't work either. Also I was wrong the above did not fix the fiddle. In your fiddle it now goes 1-2 3-4 I need it to have 1-5 stacked on the left and 6-12 stacked on the right. Thanks again for your input.